# How can I block event in root element and let the event fired in the container(parent) level?

Tags: wpf, events, event-handling, mouseleftbuttondown

I'm working with WPF.
My visual tree hierarchy as the following:
RadDiagram > RadDiagramShape > MyControl
The content of RadDiagramShape is mycontrol.

In myControl class, I have handled (MouseLeftButtonDown) Event, I put drag-drop code inside it(which I need it in another place). So, it's Direct Event not Tunneling or Bubbling!

While I'm moving  my Custom Control which is the content of the RadDiagramShape, in RadDiagram, it doesn't move (It's trying to be dragged) because the  MouseLeftButtonDown has been handled inside MyControl.
**It prevents the event from bubbling up the Visual tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.**

I tried to handled the Event for the RadDiagramShape and for the RadDiagram as `e.Handled = true;` 
but it did nothing because It's MouseLeftButtonDown and it's handled inside the root element so, it won't bubble or tunnel and I didn't override movement code, which I don't want to override it. Because I tried it before and it didn't give me the same slightly move that built-in in WPF.

**How can I block MouseLeftButtonDown event in root element and let the event fired in the container(parent) level?**

Answer (score 1):

Please check in your control handler if 'OriginalSource' is the same control that you want or not.

```js
if ((e.OriginalSource is TextBox) && (e.OriginalSource as TextBox).Name == "TextBoxName")
            {
                //Do every thing you want            
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you leila karimi. You gave me the orientation, the condition itself didn't work. But I put another condition and it worked

```
        void MyLabel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MyLabel dc = (MyLabel)sender;
            if (dc.Parent.GetType() != typeof(RadDiagramShape))
            {///....drop it}
}
```